# Как сделать мультиязычный сайт?

Tags: wordpress

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, плагин или решение, чтобы мультиязычный сайт не просто менял язык при выборе флажка уже на сайте, но чтобы еще и в конце или в начале доменного имени приписывалось ru или com, в зависимости от выбора языка.
В общем, мне нужно давать ссылки на один и тот же сайт разным людям, но чтобы у одних он открывался на английском, а у других на русском, в зависимости от того, какую ссылку я им дам.
Какие есть для этого решения?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите именно менять `.ru` на `.com` - это проблема. Так сделать сайт мультиязычным нельзя (ну если конечно не перенаправлять все, а это - полный бред).
Если вам это действительно важно (чтобы было именно ru и com) придется установить два разных сайта. Кстати, в этом нет ничего страшного (это не намного хуже чем использовать мультисайт).
Но скорее всего для вас это не принципиально. И вас наверно устроит такое разделение как ru.mysite.com и en.mysite.com; или mysite.com/ru mysite.com/en

В Вордпрессе для этого есть готовое решение. Это называется мультисайт. Читайте об этом [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8). Грубо говоря, таким образом вы получаете два сайта, но управлять ими легче чем двумя раздельными сайтами (например, можно установить и обновить плагины сразу, можно создать юзеров, которые имеют доступ ко всей сети и пр.).
Важно заметить, что некоторые планины на работают с мультисайт.

Также есть и плагины, которые реализуют функционал мультиязычности без потребности в установке мультисайта.  [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) - один из популярных. [WPML](https://wpml.org/ru/) - возможно лучше, но он платный.

Если сайт на каждом языке имеет свою структуру - установите мультисайт.
Если же структура одна, а меняется только язык - пользуйтесь плагином.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так же использовать синонимы доменного имени, отлавливать адрес по которому пришли, и соответственно отображать тот язык для которого пришли. Правда это довольно таки плохо для SEO.

Либо можно настроить редиректы в доменах и исходя из адреса с которого пришли, выставлять язык.